# ¿Cómo usar un struct desde otro archivo en C++?

Tags: c++, estructuras, struct

tengo una actividad de tarea, y me pidieron usar un struct para almacenar valores sobre productos, pero cómo puedo llamarlo desde otra clase?, es decir dónde se declara y cómo, también cómo puedo añadir valores desde otra clase. Gracias.
Este es el registro que tengo actualmente, está en una clase en el cpp, pero quiero llamarlo desde otra y poder agregar valores desde allá. Sé declara en el header o así está bien?

```
#include "inventory.h"

struct registroP{
    string barcode;
    string name;
    double weight;
    double priceW;
    double priceR;
    int quantity;
}products[500];

Inventory::Inventory(){

indice = 1;

products[0].barcode = "1234567891234";
products[0].name = "Laptops";
products[0].weight = 1.57;
products[0].priceW = 9875;
products[0].priceR = 13785;
products[0].quantity = 100;

}

void Inventory::show(){
    Product p;
    for (int i(0); i < indice; i++) {
        cout << products[i].name << endl;
        cout << products[i].barcode << endl;
        cout << products[i].weight << endl;
        cout << products[i].priceW << endl;
        cout << products[i].priceR << endl;
        cout << products[i].quantity << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, declara el struct en un fichero de *header* (por separado o en uno que ya tengas en el que tenga sentido el que esté allí). No declares la variable allí.

En tu `.h.`:

```
struct registroP {
  string barcode;
  string name;
  double weight;
  double priceW;
  double priceR;
  int quantity;
};
```

Luego importas ese .h allí donde necesites usar el tipo. Por ejemplo, en el código que muestras, queda:

```
registroP productos[500];
```

Comment: Es C++; el typedef está de más.

Comment: Muchas gracias!